# How exactly are characters stored and passed in BufferedReader involving iterations?

Tags: java, char, inputstream, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

The title might look too general, but here it is.
I found this code:

```
//class, main, etc.
char c;
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter e to exit!");

do
{
    c=(char)br.read();
    System.out.println(c);
}while(c!='q');

/*Example output:
  12ae
  1
  2
  a
  e */
  //Where I type 12ae and press enter initially
```

How exactly is the output achieved, when println() is called every time when c is assigned a value, and char can store only one character?

Shouldn't it be either(by my understanding):
In the first iteration, 
1 is passed to c,
println(c) is called,
Second iteration begins, 2 is passed and so on,

giving an output:
1
1
2
2
a
a
e
e
(Where first occurrence is my input after I press enter, second is the output with newline due to the property of println)

Or, since br is line buffered, but c can only store one character, only one character is passed after the input is entered:

In which case output would be:
12ae
e

IN A NUTSHELL:
How is multiple data(12ae) passed at once(after I hit enter, after typing) to println repeatedly?

I'm really confused, and have looked online, where I find the usual generic definitions(pun intended) but not a clear solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see what it is doing.

You are right that `c` only has one value at a time.

If you have `1 1 2 2 a a e e` as input, this is 15 characters including whitespace.

In you input

```
12ae<enter>
1<enter>
2<enter>
a<enter>
e<enter>
q
```

This will prints

```
1
2
a
e

1

2

a

e
```

as `<enter>` is a character too, often written as `\n` in Java.

> Or, since br is line buffered, but c can only store one character, only one character is passed after the input is entered:

To buffer means it holds data temporarily in memory until you need it.

It's not `br` which is line buffered, but your console. If you were to use it to read a file, it wouldn't buffer by line but rather 8192 bytes at a time by default.

> not a clear solution

This is where stepping through the code helps, you can even look at the data in the BufferedReader.